# backup file script in PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and try to write some scripts as I go along. I wrote this script and it worked. I would like to know if this script can be improved.

The purpose of the script below is to prompt the user to input the version of the backup file, and proceed to make a backup fo the Nextcloud directory.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

# prerequisites packages: apt-get install php7.4-cli php-zip

$today = date('m-d-Y');
$WWWpath = "/config/www";
$NCpath = "/config/www/nextcloud";
$user = 'xfs';
$file = 'nextcloud.zip';


chdir($NCpath);
echo "Current working directory is: " . getcwd();
echo "\n";

class Prompt
{

    protected function input()
    {
        $prompt = readline('Would you like to make a backup of the current Nextcloud ? [y|n] ' );
        echo "You selected '$prompt'\n";
        return $prompt;

    }

    public function archive()
    {
        // declare global variables
        global $WWWpath, $NCpath, $backup_version;

        $ask = $this->input();

        if(!empty($ask))
        {
            switch ($ask)
            {
                case "y":
                case "Y":
                    $backup_version = readline('Please enter a version of Nextcloud you want to backup: ');
                    echo "You input: $backup_version\n";

                    $verify = readline("Is this the correct version ? [y|n]: '{$backup_version}' ");
                    echo "You selected '$verify'.\n";

                    switch($verify)
                    {
                        case "y":
                        case "Y":
                            echo "Backup version: 'nextcloud-old_${backup_version}'\n";
                            echo "Backing up current Nextcloud directory...";
                            echo "\n";
                            $cp = ("cp -r $NCpath ${WWWpath}/'nextcloud-old_${backup_version}'");
                            $status = shell_exec("$cp");
                            $status = rtrim($status);
                            // check file copy status
                            print ((int)$status == "0") ? "File copied successfully !\n" : "Failed to copy file !\n";
                            break;

                        case "n":
                        case "N":
                            break;
                    }
                case "n":
                case "N":
                    break;
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

- using `globals` is a bad practice most of the time. In this case it is 100% sure it is a bad idea. It is better to pass the variables/values as parameters.
- for a simple script like that you do not need a class or function at all. It only makes things more complicated to reason about and to understand.
- nesting `switch` statements here is not needed at all.
- the `$ask` variable is named really poorly. It could be `$anwser` or something.
- in PHP the current standard (check out PSR) is to keep variables `camelCase`. `snake_case` is not recommended.

for the nested `switch` statements you can try "returning early" instead so they get un-nested e.g.

```php
if(strtolower($answer) !== 'y') {
   exit('You cancelled the operation.');
}


$backupVersion = readline('Please enter a version ...');
// more code here

$verify = readline("Is this the correct version ... ");
if (strtolower($verify) !== 'y') {
   exit('You cancelled the operation.');
}

// the rest of the code.
```

Comment: How do I call the variables without using them as global?

Comment: I am not sure if you're using them anywhere else. If you use them only in the archive() function you can define them within the function and use them from there.

If you use them only in that class you can define them as class properties: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

If you need to use them in several files you can use pass them as arguments https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php when calling the functions...

Or if you want to share them between files you can use namespaces https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Answer (score 1):

Just one quick remark: as per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) shell_exec returns the complete output as a string. And:

> This function can return null both when an error occurs or the program
> produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures
> using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program
> exit code is required.

If you want to retrieve the return code [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) should be used then. And it can also return the output from execution.

The variables $WWWpath, $NCpath, $backup_version should not be defined as global in your `archive` function. Instead they should be function arguments.

The switch block should be outside the `archive` function. Get the user response first, and if the response is yes then call this function with appropriate parameters.

Misc:

- I don't see the point of a class here, a function would be sufficient.
- chdir is not required, just use full paths
- you should verify that backup_version is not blank and is an appropriate value - what would happen if the user just types <kbd>Enter</kbd> ?
- a switch statement is not really needed in this case, a simple if/else will do because the answer is either yes or no and you can just cast the answer to lowercase so that Y = y
- you define a number of variables on top of your code like file, user that don't seem to be used

Comment: Hello, I'm using declare the global variables so I can use them for my 2nd part of the script. I want to use the class so the functions can be grouped together.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I'd revised the script.

Comment: and `empty()` is inappropriate when a variable is guaranteed to be declared.

Comment: I wrote it as not empty: !empty()

Comment: What I meant was that `!empty($ask)` can be safely simplified to `$ask` when `$ask` is guaranteed to be declared.